# how to make sys.stdout output/update to a file line by line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

```
sys.stdout = open("out.txt", "w")
```

I am writing code which will store console output to `out.txt` and then read it line by line and display it in tkinter gui.

I have got the last part sorted, I just want to output `sys.stdout` line by line and update the file line by line, so I can pick lines while output is produced.

Comment: Do a loop that will constantly write the output to the file.

Comment: Instead of capturing stdout to a real file, you could also use a pseudo-file with StringIO: `sys.stdout = io.StringIO()` and then you retrieve the content with `.getvalue()`

Comment: can u please share sample code? because i am confused as in what limiters to put on loop.